# Looking for a function that satisfies these boundary conditions

Tags: calculus, polynomials, circular-motion

This problem is arising in robotic motion control.

I am trying to find a function that describes $\theta(t)$ where all derivatives vanish at the boundaries 0 and $\tau$ as well as:

$$
\theta(0) = -\pi/2
$$
$$
\theta(\tau) = \pi/2
$$
In addition, the function $T(t)$ and all of its derivatives must vanish at the boundaries, where
$$
T(t) = a\ddot{\theta} + b\cos\theta
$$

I would think this is a well-studied problem, since $T(t)$ describes the dynamics of a rod rotating against gravity, but I can't come up with anything on my own or find anything in the literature.

Comment: Your wording is confusing. What do you mean all derivatives vanish at the boundaries? Do you mean only the first derivative? The second part this is strange to me is that even if you are talking about the first derivative, you have specified four boundary conditions for a second order ODE. This can be ill-posed. Are you sure it is not two conditions?

Comment: To address your question on whether or not this particular problem is a well-studied problem. A standard approach in physics is to note that when $F = m \ddot \theta$ can be written $dV/d\theta = m \ddot \theta$ then you can obtain a first integral by multiplying both sides by $\dot \theta$. But here you have a time-dependent potential.

Comment: Apart from the "All derivatives" part that @Gregory already brought up, your problem description looks incomplete. You have two unknown functions but only one ODE.